# Cross Domain AJAX GET Chrome Extension won't work!

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't get this to work - I'm following the actual docs, as well as this example:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/howto/contentscript_xhr/

I'm simply trying to GET json data, formatted to the browser screen like so: **{"name":"value"}**, from a URL, but get a "null" value returned when I alert.

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Does a GET request cross-domain.",
  "background_page": "plugin.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "",
    "default_icon": "icon.ico"
  }
}
```

My plugin.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function fetchData(callback) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        callback(req.responseText);
                    } else {
                        callback(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            var url = 'http://foo/bar.php';
            req.open('GET', url, true);
            req.send();
        };

        function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
            if (request.action == 'fetchData') {
                fetchData(callback);
            }
        };

        chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);

        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url: 'index.html'});
        });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
    </head>
        <body>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                  function onReturn(data) {
                   alert('Data ' + data);
                };
                  chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'fetchData'}, onReturn);
              </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duh.  [chrome extension - ip domain permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258206/chrome-extension-ip-domain-permissions)

```
http://*/*
```

Comment: I'd suggest limiting the permissions you request to the actual domains you'll be pulling data from. No reason to request access to the whole Internet if you only need host permissions to one domain. :)

Comment: Haha.  Not a terrible suggestion by any means.