# Get JSON in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

Small problem with my chrome extension.

I just wanted to get a JSON array from another server. But manifest 2 doesn't allow me to do it. I tried specify `content_security_policy`, but the JSON array is stored on a server without SSL cert.

So, what should I do without using manifest 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258206/chrome-extension-ip-domain-permissions read this post, it will hopefully help you out

Comment: I don't get it. I have correct permissions in my manifest. But the problem is, that jQuery $.getJSON function can't work without content_security_policy settings. But content_security_policy accepts only HTTPS pages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) cannot cause the problem you've described. It's very likely that you're using JSONP instead of plain JSON. JSONP does not work in Chrome, because JSONP works by inserting a `<script>` tag in the document, whose `src` attribute is set to the URL of the webservice. [This is disallowed by the CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading).

Provided that you've set the correct permission in the manifest file (e.g. `"permissions": ["http://domain/getjson*"]`, you will always be able to get and parse the JSON:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    var json = xhr.responseText;                         // Response
    json = json.replace(/^[^(]*\(([\S\s]+)\);?$/, '$1'); // Turn JSONP in JSON
    json = JSON.parse(json);                             // Parse JSON
    // ... enjoy your parsed json...
};
// Example:
data = 'Example: appended to the query string..';
xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain/getjson?data=' + encodeURIComponent(data));
xhr.send();
```

When using jQuery for ajax, make sure that JSONP is not requested by using `jsonp: false`:

```
$.ajax({url:'...',
        jsonp: false ... });
```

Or, when using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('URL which does NOT contain callback=?', ...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! I don't know what happened, but it works without callback=? like a charm! It didn't work in the past, but now it's OK :-) So solved!

Comment: The real first working exemple i found in the web on hours of search and try. If i Use: var json = this.response; i get it working. What is the difference than responseText ?