# Chrome extension external ajax call by jquery not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I really googled a lot but found no answer which covers my question.

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to make an ajax call by jquery.
I make it like this:

**popup.js**

```
$(function()
{
    $('#btn').click(function()
    {
        $('#wait').html('loading...');
        jQuery.getJSON("http://domain.com/extension_php_files/generate.php?callback=?",
        {id:25}, 
        function(data) 
        {
            $('#wait').html('');
            console.log( JSON.stringify(data) ) 
            $.each(data, function(key, val) 
            {
                alert(key + '  ' + val);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And here is my **popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="#" id="btn">SEND</a><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <span id="wait"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

And
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "black",
  "description": "black here",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "http://domain.com/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

When I click on the `SEND` button, I see `Loading...` but it never goes into success function. I googled but couldn't figure out the problem.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: My server side code works just fine.

Comment: Asked and answered before: [Get JSON in chrome plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842954/get-json-in-chrome-plugin)

Comment: @RobW I've been read all questions about my problem in stackoverflow.

Comment: I understand. I've got lots of experience with writing extensions, and posted many answers in the google-chrome-extension tag, so I can easily identify the core issue and find the corresponding Q&A, even if the wording of the question is slightly different. The answer on the linked question exactly targets your specific problem. If you apply the [proposed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11845618/938089), your extension will start working like a charm.

Comment: @RobW So what should i do if my problem still exists? (even when i read that answers)

Comment: Try the answer first, and post a *tested* demo with the problem. Your question says that the button etc. show up, but I know that the posted example might not be accurate since the syntax of the manifest file is invalid (if you used this file literally, your extension won't load at all).

Comment: @RobW thanks for your comments. but it was happened during the copy-paste. I corrected it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26848/discussion-between-siamak-a-m-and-rob-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for [**Rob W**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w)'s helps.
I removed `?callback=?` at the end of the url. And on server side page I did something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['$id'];
$arr = array ("id"=>$id,"name"=>"Siamak","lname"=>"Aghaeipour","age"=>"24");
$jsonData =  json_encode($arr);
echo $jsonData;
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also sometimes have hard time with  jquery ajax request, and I the best solution for me is just to replace that code with native javascript Ajax code. Try to make request using  XMLHttpRequest like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("GET", "http://domain.com/", true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

          // paste your code here 
       }
     }
     xhr.send();
```

replace the http://domain.com/ with your complete url

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i really Insisted to do it with jquery ajax method. thanks for your answer :)

Comment: i was using $.getJSON and it`s async state was driving me crazy. Going vanilla xhr this way has brougth my mind back to sanity :)