# Link stored in var, get content in another var

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a link stored in a variable and i want to get it's content in another var. The page itself is a XML page. I understood that it can be done within php, but i am curious if there is any way to get it through jQuery of javascript. I use it inside a chrome extension and php is useless from what i've understood.

Comment: Are you looking for [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) (or [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), or [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/))? That lets you fetch web pages (and handle their content) without navigating away from your current page. Normally Ajax requests are limited by the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents `foo.com` from fetching pages on `bar.com`, but Chrome extensions can [bypass this restriction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html).

Comment: I just want to parse some xml page whose link is stored in a variable. Naturally i want it's content to be stored in another variable before i parse it ( though it's not necessary )
I will look further on on the bypass thing, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>"
    ,xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml )
    ,$xml = $( xmlDoc )
    ,$title = $xml.find( "title" );
```

If your XML would contain a `a` tags, you could get them all using `$xml.find('a')`.

> "[This](http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=microsoft) Where microsoft is replaced by another word."

Given the new comments you posted, if you want to use Google's suggest API from the browser, you will not be able to work with XML. As far as I know, that API is not designed to be used by external tiers and it will not accept cross-domain requests. However, there is still a way to use the API, but as a result of the work around, you will have to work with a different data format.

http://jsfiddle.net/XF8WC/

Here, we specify **youtube** as the `client` url param, wich allows us to use JSONP to retrieve data, because the API's return format is based on the `client`.

For more informations, please refer to **[this article](http://blog.shreyaschand.com/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/)**.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com/complete/search',
    data: {
        client: 'youtube',
        q: 'microsoft',
        jsonp: 'searchCallback'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});

window.searchCallback = function (data) {
    $.each(data[1], function (index, item) {
        console.log(item[0]); //log suggestion
    });
}
```

Comment: Well it means i can store my link under the `var xml`and then continue just like in the example ? I'm confused about how i can actually get the data from the link stored in the `var link` and pass the content in another var for parsing.

Comment: @Edeph, Can you show some part of your XML and what you are trying to access?

Comment: [This](http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=microsoft) Where microsoft is replaced by another word.

Comment: Actually how do i use ajax inside the extension ? The log points out an error.

Comment: @Edeph, hum... forgot about the extension thing, you can read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955199/jquery-ajax-call-fails-inside-chrome-extension, hopefull you will find a solution to run ajax there.